# Array iteration in multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I've got the following example, let's say I want for each thread to count from 0 to 9.

```
void* iterate(void* arg) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i<10) {
        i++;
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main() {
    int j = 0;        
    pthread_t tid[100];
    while(j<100) {
        pthread_create(&tid[j],NULL,iterate,NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[j],NULL);
    }
}
```

variable i - is in a critical section, it will be overwritten multiple times and therefore threads will fail to count.

```
int* i=(int*)calloc(1,sizeof(int));
```

doesn't solve the problem either. I don't want to use mutex. What is the most common solution for this problem?

Comment: You don't *have* a problem. Each thread has it's own local `i` variable. It isn't shared between them, at all.

Comment: Variable `i` is a local variable, which means there's a separate `i` for each thread. Also, you're only running one thread at a time anyways. By calling `pthread_join` after `pthread_create`, you force `main` to wait for one thread to finish before creating the next thread. Not to mention the fact that you never increment `j`, so the loop is infinite.

Comment: so, if i decide to initialize a new variable inside a thread, then thread gets its own variable with unique address, and which can't be accessed by any other thread?

Comment: @ArtEm, true for local variables, not for file or global scope.

Comment: Did you intend for `i` to be shared between the threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users are commenting, there are severals problems in your example:

1. Variable `i` is not shared (it should be a global variable, for instance), nor in a critical section (it is a local variable to each thread). To have a critical section you should use locks or transactional memory.
2. You don't need to create and destroy threads every iteration. Just create a number of threads at the beggining and wait for them to finish (*join*).
3. `pthread_exit()` is not necessary, just return from the thread function (with a value).
4. A counter is a bad example for threads. It requires atomic operations to avoid overwriting the value of other threads. Actually, a multithreaded counter is a typical example of why atomic accesses are necessary (see [this tutorial](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/), for example).

I recommend you to start with some tutorials, like [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) or [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15492-f07/www/pthreads.html).

I also recommend frameworks like OpenMP, they simplify the semantics of multithreaded programs.

**EDIT:** example of a shared counter and 4 threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 4

static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static int counter = 0;

void* iterate(void* arg) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i++ < 10) {
        // enter critical section
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        ++counter;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    int j;        
    pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
    for(j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; ++j)
        pthread_create(&tid[j],NULL,iterate,NULL);

    // let the threads do their magic

    for(j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; ++j)
        pthread_join(tid[j],NULL);

    printf("%d", counter);

    return 0;
}
```